# Normalized database table with non-atomic values

Tags: database-design, normalization

I'm creating a normalized table for a questionnaire that the customers fill in and in one of the columns is a field called "extra comments". I realize that with the "extra comments" field, the data will not be atomic as the customers may be writing sentences or can the sentences be considered as atomic values? How do I keep the "extra comments" field and keep the table normalized?

Comment: Can you provide existing design? Does comment field relate to whole questionnaire or to each question?

Comment: Yes, sentence -- any text can be considered "atomic". The domain of that column is `customer comment`-- set of all possible customer comments.So, each row-column intersection contains exactly one customer comment.

Comment: So if the comments sections was like a list, would that still be considered atomic? For example, the "extra comments" was for extra suggestions, and the customer gave a list of suggestions, is that still atomic?

Comment: If the domain is `customer comment` than trying to insert more than one is not atomic. Google "What First Normal Form Really Means". You have to understand the concept of domain.

Comment: I understand that, but how do i go about putting multiple suggestions for one person into a normalised table?